# Count working days of a date interval (period) inside another given date interval (period)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have several periods. Right now I use a formula to count how many days fall within one period taking another period into account.

For example period 1 has 26 days that fall within the project period. There can be many project periods, but period 1 to 12 will be the same always

Project Period : 20-12-2018 to 15-03-2019

Period 1: 15-12-2018 to 14-01-2019 (26 days)

Period 2: 15-12-2018 to 14-02-2019 (31 days)

Period x etc.

=IF(MAX(MIN($N$7;O4)-MAX($M$7;O3)+1)<0;0;MAX(MIN($N$7;O4)-MAX($M$7;O3)+1))

I need to find out how many working days of period 1,2...12. fall within the project period. The result should be 13 for period 1, when subtracting holidays and weekends. For that I'm using the

=NETWORKDAYS(M7;O4;Holidays)

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that cells A1 & B1 include start and end dates for the project and A2 and B2 are the start and end dates for period 1:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(MAX($A$1,A2),MIN($B$1,B2))
```

This will give you the number for workdays in the period (Monday through Friday).
If you want to exclude holidays like 31-12-2018 or 01-01-2019 you need to provide a list of holidays as the optional third argument. 
For example, if you have a list of holidays you want to exclude in column F row 1 to 10 your formula would be

```
=NETWORKDAYS(MAX($A$1,A2),MIN($B$1,B2),F1:F10)
```

In case you do not want to exclude weekends use the DAYS function instead but be aware that in this function the first argument is the end date while the second argument is the start date.

Comment: THANKS alot. It does exactly what I need!